# How to set Spyder 4 for my existing python environment (OSX)

Tags: python, macos, spyder, openpyxl

I'm new to python coding and I'm using OSX.
I installed Python 3.9 and openpyxl using Brew (if I understood correctly Brew puts everything in /usr/local).
With Brew Cask I also installed Spyder 4.
In Sypder 4 I didn't find openpyxl so, following a guide, I tried to change the interpreter selecting the Python 3.9 installed under /usr/local (here the path "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9").

I get this error

> "Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the spyder‑kernels module or the right version of it installed (>= 1.10.0 and < 1.11.0). Without this module is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you."

I'm stuck and I need help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I installed spyder-kernels using pip3.